# How can I setup this discount on a Drupal Commerce website?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-commerce

I have a site with 6 differnet products - each one costs £2.99

What I need to do, is for between the 1st August and 31st August, all sauces are 2 for £5. So for example, if a visitor buys 1 sauce they just pay the £2.99. If they buy 2 sauces their total is £5, if they buy 4 it's £10, 6 is £15 and so on.. So every two products they buy costs £5.

Thanks for reading, really hope someone can give me some pointers as this needs to go live as of 1st August.

Comment: What code have you tried so far in your module?

Comment: Hello I haven't written my own module, I'm trying to use contrib modules as I'm not a developer. I'm trying to use the rules and the discount modules, but just can't figure out how to do this. Thanks for the quick reply by the way.

Comment: Is this the module you are using? https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount_product_category You may want to consult the documentation for you module to see if you can do what you need without any custom code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've just tried that module but don't think it's what I'm looking for. What I currently have is all 6 products are 2.99. For every 2 products the user buys, I want this to be £5. So for example one products would be 2.99, two would be £5. three would be 7.99 (£5 for 2 plus 2.99 for one), four would be £10, five would be 12.99 (£10 for 4 plus 2.99 for one) etc... I hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few items to investigate:
This is a little old but it'll give you an idea of the Rules you are trying to create if you do it manually. See the [last comment](https://drupalcommerce.org/comment/6451#comment-6451).
The [Commerce Discount Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount_extra) module or the might do the trick. There is also [Commerce Discount Quantity](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount_quantity), but it doesn't have a full release yet, you could check in the issue queue to see if the maintainer is planning a full release soon.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, I shall look into this now

Answer (score 0):

You could add a rule that divides the number of items ($num-items) by two ($div-two), only in cases where $num-items is > 1.

Store the modulo in variable $modu.

If $modu == 0, then simply apply a £5 price times $div-two for the total. If $modu == 1, then apply £5 times ($num-items - 1), + £2.99.